# Getting Computer Memory information in Java

Tags: java, memory, process, ram

Is there any application for **memory testing**, preferably written in **java** (or another programming language) that shows information about **computer memory** or something for testing it (something like **total memory**, **free memory** , **processes and memory consumption** etc.). I want something like the **resource monitor** from `Windows`: [image: Resource Monitor screenshot]  ... or something similar.

I need the source code.

Comment: You can Profile your project using any IDE

Comment: @user1143825 This isn't about profiling.

Comment: Testing requared 'expected' result and 'actual'. What is expected result in your testing?

Answer (score 3):

There is no integrated API to do this.

On Windows, I suggest you execute [systeminfo](http://ss64.com/nt/systeminfo.html) using ProcessBuilder :

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("systeminfo");
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = processBuilder.start();
String output = readOutput(process);
try {
    if (process.waitFor() != 0) {
        throw new IOException(
            "command exited in error: " + process.exitValue()
                + "\n" + output);
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// here parse output for what you want
```

The output of systeminfo is like this :

```
Total Physical Memory: xxx MB
Available Physical Memory: xxx MB
Page File: Max Size: xxxx MB
Page File: Available: xxxx MB
Page File: In Use: xxx MB
```

Comment: What can I do then for memory testing in java ?

Comment: What do you mean "memory testing" ? This gives you the memory available & the total, both physical and in swap.

Comment: I have to do an application regarding the computer memory for an essay.All it says in the description for this application is this:"Testing the memory of a computer".Also,I'm confused,that is why I'm asking for help or suggestion about what should I do regarding the memory and why I was thinking about something like that resource monitor.I was thinking about something with an interface (GUI).Thank You.

Comment: @TeoRoxy Then you probably should get more information about the task before you start and go the wrong direction. "Memory testing" could mean so much different things.

Comment: @TeoRoxy The purpose of SO isn't to make your whole application. Asking for technical questions on specific points (like how to get the memory info) is OK. Asking for your whole application isn't. Ask another question if **after having tried** to make a GUI you have problems.

Comment: Can you give me some examples about what you're thinking?Thank you.

Comment: @TeoRoxy If I was meant in you last comment: See [memtest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memtest86)

Comment: @denys-séguret the above code doesn't compile without an implementation of readOutput.  Were you thinking something like:<br>  
`private String readOutput( Process process ) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
            builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }`